# How to style each Geometry of a GeoJSON GeometryCollection individually using Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

I'm working on an interactive map showing the history of rail transport in a city using Leaflet and some GeoJSON data. My GeoJSON data looks like this:

```
var lines = [
    {
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "name": "stadtmitte_gerresheim",
        "startYear": "1902",
        "endYear": "2019",
        "lineColor": "#DD0000",
        "trainID": "001",
        "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "lineName": "U73",
                "station1": "Universität Ost/Botanischer Garten",
                "station2": "Gerresheim S",
                "startYear": "2016",
                "endYear": "2019",
                "lineColor": "#DD0000",
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "GeometryCollection",
                "geometries": [
                    {
                        "type": "LineString",
                        "lineID": "001",
                        "lineDescription": "Schleife am S-Bahnhof Gerresheim",
                        "coordinates": [...
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "LineString",
                        "lineID": "002",
                        "lineDescription": "Gerresheim S bis Ecke Schönaustraße/Heyestraße",
                        "coordinates": [...
                        ]
                    }
....
```

I'm working with several FeatureCollections, that consist of some Features. As you can see the geometry of each feature is defined by a GeometryCollection (that mostly comprises LineStrings).

I'd like to use Leaflet to style each single geometry (the LineStrings from the GeometryCollections) according to its members. At the moment I only manage to style the whole GeometryCollection via the Feature:

```
L.geoJSON(route, {
                filter: function(feature) {
                    if (checkYear(feature)) {
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                },
                style: function(feature) {
                    switch (feature.properties.tunnel) {
                        case 'yes': return {color: "#ff0000", dashArray: "1,6"};
                        default: return {color: "#ff0000"}
                    }
                },
                pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
                    getIconSize();
                    switch (feature.properties.underground) {
                        case 'yes': return L.marker(latlng, {icon: stadtbahnIcon});
                        default: return L.marker(latlng, {icon: strassenbahnIcon});
                    }
                }
            }).addTo(mymap);
        }
```

My question: Is it possible to hand individual style functions to different Geometries of the same Feature instead of handing the same style function to all Geometries in this Feature? And if so, how? I guess it should be possible, as Leaflet creates a single path for every Geometry.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to hand individual style functions to different Geometries of the same Feature?

No.

Leaflet creates one instance of `L.Layer` per `Feature` in the GeoJSON, [right over here](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/0873b2b140c781e29dda96c41a2171b3105a9a72/src/layer/GeoJSON.js#L164); and the application of the `style` callback function [just loops over the `L.Layer`s corresponding to each feature](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/0873b2b140c781e29dda96c41a2171b3105a9a72/src/layer/GeoJSON.js#L141), it doesn't drill down on nested `L.LayerGroup`s (also, the `L.Polyline`s and `L.Polygon`s created as the result of a `GeometryCollection` don't have a reference to the original GeoJSON feature nor its properties).

I guess you'll want to use [TurfJS' `geomEach`](http://turfjs.org/docs#geomEach) (or something similar) in order to preprocess your features&geometries.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for!